# While deploying, the userid and password isn't the one from ConnectionString

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014, webdeploy

When executing Visual studio web application (debugging mode), it uses admin/1234 as credentials as mentioned web.config but after deploying it, it asks me to create credentials with username: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool and with this newly created one, I am able to proceed further.

Where am i going wrong? Ideally it should extract the username and password from connectionString and the same should be used when I deploy. Why should I create a new login id in MS Sql Server Manager with username IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool.?

This part is more vague and weird to me. Could you please explain where I went wrong and why I am experiencing this behavior??

Thanks.

Comment: How does it "ask you to create credentials"?  Do you have any config transforms or parameterization setup for the config file?

Comment: Well, if I don't create with those credentials, I get the following error message.. Cannot open database "UserDetails" requested by the login. The login failed.  Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. Where "UserDetails" is my db. After setting the username and password, is able to access the db.

Comment: Does your connection string specify a username/password?  If not, its likely using the integrated auth.  Use SQL creds instead.

Comment: I remember I have set username and password in connection string. Will anyways check and update. Thanks.